# I want to print when the user fails to type a positive number it will tell them the number was not valid (eg -8.25)

Tags: python

```
def itemPrices():
    items = []
    while True:
        itemAmount = float(input("Enter the amount for the item: "))
        if itemAmount < 0:
            continue
        again = input("Do you want to add another item? Enter 'y' for yes and 'n' for no: ")
        items.append(itemAmount)

        if again == "y":
            continue

        elif again == "n":
            numItems = len(items)
            print(f"You purchased {numItems} items.")
            sumAmount = sum(items)
            print(f"The total for this purchase is {sumAmount} before tax.")
            print(f"The average amount for this purchase is {sumAmount/numItems}.")
            if numItems >= 10:
                tax = (9/100)*sumAmount
            else:
                tax = (9.5/100)*sumAmount

            print(f"You owe ${tax} in tax.")
            

            break
        else:
            print("Invalid input")
            continue

    
itemPrices()
```

Comment: You already check `if itemAmount < 0`. Why not `print()` inside that conditional? Do you have a specific question? Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), 
and provide a [mre]. Please also read [how much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953). Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:

    user_input = input("type a number")

    try:
        if float(user_input) < 0:
            print('this number is less than zero please try again')
            continue
        else:
            print("good job this number is valid")
            # place the code you want to execute when number is positive here
            break

    except ValueError:
        print("this is not a number please enter a valid number")
        continue
```